# How to encrypt SQLite (seeded/otherwise) database when used with RestKit

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption, restkit, sqlcipher

I am using RestKit to perform database seeding, as well as perform local persistence. The related Core Data and Object Mapping are working as expected. However, I need to encrypt the local database now. I know that the following options are generally used to protect SQLite database

1. Use some kind of a MDM/Profile Manager with Lion Server, to secure application data (remote wipe etc.)
2. Use SQLCipher to encrypt database

However, SQLCipher does not work with RestKit. Anybody been in a situation like this, anything  else to encrypt the local SQLite? I would like to continue to use RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really necessary. While not an exact answer, [this](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/) may be helpful for you. You are free to edit the RestKit source to add the NSFileProtectionComplete code or you can ask for a feature enhancement on their github area.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I guess the link definitely gives a pretty good picture of what I am trying to do and explains a few limitations. The best way to do that in my mind is having to go for a 'multi-layered security architecture' that basically tightens screws on all the layers in the application lifecycle.